# What's the correct way to layout the views of child UIViewControllers in a custom UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

When subclassing `UIViewController` or `UINavigationViewController`, and you have a header view or something that should restrict child views to a smaller portion of the screen, how do you go about setting the size of these child controller views? Apple's internal solutions like `topLayoutGuide` are read-only and inaccessible. UINavigationController doesn't allow you to change its root view either, so overriding layoutSubviews won't work.

Comment: Not getting you.

Comment: you have a header view or something that should restrict child views to a smaller portion of the screen, can you please explain in detail?